# Make sense of an Xml GET file and make meaningful array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have to turn files such as this one, received via GET, into manageable arrays to be written in DB. I have not much knowledge of Xml, though I tried to learn, they are still hieroglyphics. Could please somebody help me out? These files are not all similar to the example code and it would interesting to have some kind of Php flexible function to which pass the node, or from such a node downwards, to be returned as a key=>value array. I have tried `array_map('read_xml', xpath('//node_to_be_parsed'))`, found on this forum, but the returned array is empty, Maybe the

```
function read_xml(SimpleXMLElement $node_to_be_parsed)
{ 
    $array = array();
    foreach ($product->a_node as $some_node) 
        { $array[(string)$some_node["attr"]] = (string)$a_node; }
    return $array;
}
```

is too simple.  Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you all. Martin

```
<envelope>
    <header>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <timestamp>20141030174828</timestamp>
    </header>
    <response type="Response type" product="songs">
        <search number="66637"/>
        <nights number="7"/>
        <checkin date="2014-11-15"/>
        <checkout date="2014-11-22"/>
        <songs>
            <song id="32" name="A name" vote="9" country="Country" city="City">
                <agreement id="Agreement Id 100" available="true" matched="true" c_type="7" room_basis="FB" meal_basis="A" rental_type="CC" checkindays="SAT" itinerary_id="91" itinerary_name="Itinerary Name" name="A title" min_nights="7" currency="EUR" deadline="2014-11-01" total="2257.92" total_compulsory_remarks="80.00" total_compulsory_on_place="300.00" special="true">
                    <remarks>
                        <remark text="Remark text ABC" id="689"></remark>
                        <remark text="Remark text DEF" id="690"></remark>
                        <remark text="Remark text GHI" id="309">
                            <structured applicable="pax" inadvance="true" toadd="true" compulsory="true">
                                <ammount calculated_child_value="0" child_value="25" type="EUR" calculated_value="80" value="40"/>
                            </structured>
                        </remark>
                        <remark text="Remark text XXX" id="2833">
                            <structured applicable="pax" inadvance="false" toadd="true" compulsory="true">
                                <ammount calculated_child_value="0" child_value="150" type="EUR" calculated_value="300" value="150"/>
                            </structured>
                        </remark>
                        <remark text="Remark text YYY" id="2835"></remark>
                        <remark text="Remark text ZZZ" id="2836">
                            <structured applicable="pax" inadvance="true" toadd="true" compulsory="false">
                                <ammount calculated_child_value="0" child_value="125" type="EUR" calculated_value="250" value="125"/>
                            </structured>
                        </remark>
                    </remarks>
                    <room type="Aaa" required="2">
                        <price from="2014-11-15" to="2014-11-22">
                            <roomprice nett="1128.96" child="1128.96" />
                        </price>
                    </room>
                </agreement>
                <agreement id="Agreement Id 200" available="true" matched="true" c_type="16" room_basis="FB" meal_basis="A" rental_type="CC" checkindays="SAT" itinerary_id="91" itinerary_name="Itinerary name" name="A name" min_nights="7" currency="EUR" deadline="2014-11-01" total="3517.92" total_compulsory_remarks="80.00" total_compulsory_on_place="0.00">
                    <remarks>
                        <remark text="................." id="689"></remark>
                            <structured applicable="......................">
                                <ammount calculated_child_value="0" child_value="250" type="USD" calculated_value="800" value="350"/>
                            </structured>
                    </remarks>
                    <room type="Bbb" required="2">
                        <price from="......." to=".">
                            <roomprice nett="......" child="......." />
                        </price>
                    </room>
                </agreement>
            </song>
        </songs>
    </response>
</envelope>
```

Comment: What sort of information you want to have from this XML?

Comment: I'll have to write some DB records (unknown yet), therefore it would be useful to point at some node and/or attr and get that array. Or, in an ideal world, pass a node name and get an array from that node downwards. The array has to be key=>value to identify columns. The Xml looks rather complicated to me. Hope I understood your question and answered correctly. Otherwise ask again, thanks Martin

Comment: Ok, well suppose if we have `<room type="Aaa" required="2">
                        <price from="2014-11-15" to="2014-11-22">
                            <roomprice nett="1128.96" child="1128.96" />
                        </price>
                    </room>` What sort of information you will update from this node?

Comment: room type | required | price from | to | roomprice nett | child